# PhoneGap Barcode Scanner Plugin (ZXing) on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, barcode-scanner

I have been using the Barcode Scanner Phonegap plugin on Android, and tried to implement the same on iOS. However it seems like the documentation is outdated. The Github README.md file does not really apply to the current version of Xcode and latest ZXing library. I am using Xcode 4.6.2. I tried to follow the instructions from [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner) on iOS 6.1 but many things are different. My code compiles but it does not seem to be able to call the scanner. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see any error in the log?  iOS also require a different barcode scanner js than the android version.  You also need to reference the plugin in config.xml like so: <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner" value="CDVBarcodeScanner"/>

Comment: Yes, that was not a problem. I tried the solution on the answer below and it works. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/zeroasterisk/PhoneGap-BarcodeScanner-Example-iOS#readme) works. It is the same plugin updated by @zeroasterisk. It does the trick, until PhoneGap guys update the plugin.